# ¿ Como validar que input de tipo file no esta vació?

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo un botón deshabilitado en mi modulo, pero quiero que se habilite si mi input de tipo file  se encuentra con algún valor, es decir si seleccione un archivo. Estoy usando JQuery.

Probé las siguientes lineas sin lograr obtener un resultado favorable

```
$("#Ingresar").prop("disabled", true);


$('#file').bind('click', function(e){

 if( $('#file').val() > 0){

    $("#Ingresar").prop("disabled", false);
  }

});
```

También lo probé con change y selected

Comment: Lo cambie a .on y no funciona tampoco, gracias por responder igualmente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El `input[type=file]` tiene una propiedad llamada [`files`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) donde te da los archivos seleccionados. Solo tendrias que verificar si el `length` es igual a 0, si lo es deshabilitas el boton, de lo contrario lo habilitas:

```js
$("#fileInput").change(function(){
    $("button").prop("disabled", this.files.length == 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" id="fileInput" />

<button disabled="disabled">Enviar</button>
```

Comment: Gracias, funciono perfecto

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a controlar los cambios del input file de esta forma:

```
$("#file").on('change', function() {
    if ($('#file').val()) { 
         $("#Ingresar").prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Al hacer esto y seleccionar un archivo, el botón sigue deshabilitado, gracias por responder igualmente.